# Scaling with circles in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a circle so that  it's not stretched into a ellipse when used with `xscale=` and `yscale=` options. MWE of the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.005cm,xscale=0.02cm]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (18.0,0) node[right] {$f_1$};
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,100.0) node[above] {$f_2$};

   \draw[fill=purple!60] (0,0) -- (0,75) --  (5,95) -- (10,90) -- (13.6,74.4) -- (15.0,60.0) -- cycle;
   \draw [fill=teal] (5,95) circle [radius=0.4cm];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Circle is stretched]

Comment: Related/duplicate(?): [Change TikZ Scale for One Path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266838)

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using `x=` and `y=` to define the linear distances rather than scaling the `x` and `y` separately.

Comment: What about `\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a node instead of the direct draw like this:

```
\node [draw, circle, fill=teal, minimum size=.4cm] at (5,95) {};
```

then, your circle will still be the same.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.005cm,xscale=0.02cm]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (18.0,0) node[right] {$f_1$};
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,100.0) node[above] {$f_2$};

   \draw[fill=purple!60] (0,0) -- (0,75) --  (5,95) -- (10,90) -- (13.6,74.4) -- (15.0,60.0) -- cycle;
   %\draw [fill=teal] (5,95) circle [radius=0.4cm];
   \node [draw, circle, fill=teal, minimum size=.4cm] at (5,95) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]